# Chrome is not rendering chunked json response

Tags: node.js, http, http-headers, http-streaming

I want to make a streaming endpoint that keeps sending a json object. I have tried using chunked transfer encoding and was able to successfully make all the browsers (chrome, firefox, safari) render the data sent from the server if it was either text/html or text/plain. But when I use application/json as the content-type it does not work on chrome. Here's the code:

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function(request, response){
    response.setHeader('Connection', 'Transfer-Encoding');
    response.setHeader('Transfer-Encoding', 'chunked');
    response.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
    // response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');


    setInterval(function(){     
        response.write('test </br>');   
         // response.write('{"test": "test"}');
    }, 10);

}).listen(8000);
```

The above code works as expected, but cant make it work with the application/json type. Am I missing something ?

Comment: Google Chrome renders the output in real-time at "view source" mode. See `view-source:http://localhost:8000/`. What is expected behavior?

Comment: This is the expected behaviour. So, if I view twitter streaming api through chrome browser same thing will happen right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in browsers. and its fixed in latest chrome(at least in canary).

[Chrome Bug - Transfer-Encoding chunked not support on text/plain](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=chunked&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Iteration%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified&groupby=&sort=&id=156023)

Safari (i have tested on Mac OSX) is the only browser that is not rendering the non-html content with chunked encoding.

Comment: looks like they fixed it now. only safari on Mac is not working.